# Why sometimes the number of total-votes is different between various communities?

Tags: bug, network-profile, score

I think the algorithm of calculating the number of votes for each question/answer is different between different communities.

Here is one of my question on the **StackExchange**:

[image]

As you see, StackExchange shows the number of total_votes of that question is **6**.

Here is the same question in the **stackverflow**:

[image]

And as you see, stackoverflow shows the number of total_votes of that question is **4**. *(even there isn't any downvote which makes a error-possibility in the calculation)*

Well, why there is two different number as total-votes-number for on question when I open it on stachoverflow and stackexchange *(list of questions)* ?

I always taught all communities use of an identical algorithm for every task. But it seems wrong ...!

Comment: [I blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: @MichaelT Well, what you linked is really and really proper in this situation.

Comment: @MichaelT Really? Was my first thought as well. But consider dates of posting please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are two hard problems in computing - cache invalidation, naming and off by one errors. I blame caching still.  The [suggestion on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312438) is that deletion / invalidation of votes may not force a reload of the cached data on the network profile.

Comment: @MichaelT Fair point.